# Transferring image into a certain folder, doesn't work no error message

Tags: php, image, forms, upload

I've searched the internet for about an hour and found nothing that suited my needs, so i hope you can help me.

story:
I have got a web site with a form where you can order something. You´re also able to upload an image if you want to. This image should be transferred (together with a .txt file that contains the details) into a folder which is created.
But it doesn't work as it should

My technique:

I only use php for validation. The form is submitted is send to itself and after passing the validation successfully the form data is saved in a session in order to guarantee access for the .php file that handles the data. The file handling the data has three main functions:
handle_form (the function called which wraps all other tasks and functions)
move_image (the function which should transfer the image)
create_auftrag (the function which creates the folder and the .txt file)

Everything works perfectly except the move_image form and I just don´t why. So here´s the code of the file validating the form:

```
    <?php 

$error_style = "";
$variante = 0;
$first_time = true;
$varianten_error = "";
$fehler = false;
echo $_POST["varianten"];
if ($_POST["varianten"] == "vorlage") {
            $variante = 1;
        } elseif ($_POST["varianten"] == "digital") {
            $variante = 2;
            $varianten_error.= $variante;
        } elseif ($_POST["varianten"] == "hardcopy") {
            $variante = 3;
            $varianten_error.= $variante;
        }

if(isset($_POST["form_id"]))
{
    include_once("assets/scripts/php/formvalidation.inc.php");

    // Neues Testobjekt erstellen
    $pruefung= new FormValidation("auftragsformular");

    // Prüfungen für Felder definieren
    $pruefung->requireField("name", new FieldFilled(), "Bitte geben Sie einen Namen ein.");
    $pruefung->requireField("email", new FieldEmail(), "Bitte geben Sie eine Email-Adresse an.");
    $pruefung->requireField("plz", new FieldZipCode(), "Bitte geben Sie eine Postleitzahl ein.");
    $pruefung->requireField("ort", new FieldFilled(), "Bitte geben Sie einen Ort an.");
    $pruefung->requireField("strasse", new FieldFilled(), "Bitte geben Sie eine Straße ein.");
    $pruefung->requireField("hausnr", new FieldNumber(), "Bitte geben Sie eine Hausnummer an.");
    $pruefung->requireField("hoehe", new FieldNumber(), "Bitte geben Sie die Höhe Ihres Sicherungskastens an.");
    $pruefung->requireField("breite", new FieldNumber(), "Bitte geben Sie die Breite Ihres Sicherungskastens an.");
    $pruefung->requireField("agb", new FieldFilled(), "Bitte akzeptieren Sie die AGB.");
    $pruefung->requireField("varianten", new FieldFilled(), "Bitte wählen Sie eine Variante aus.");


    // Prüfung ausführen
    if($pruefung->check())
    {
        // Weiterverarbeitung der Formulardaten
        if ($variante == 1) {
            if (!isset($_POST['vorlagen'])) {
                $varianten_error .= "Bitte wählen sie eine Vorlage aus.";
                $fehler = true;
            }
        } elseif ($variante == 2) {
            if (!isset($_FILES['upload'])) {
                $varianten_error .= "Bitte laden sie ein Bild hoch.";
                $fehler = true;
            } elseif ($bildinfo === false) {
                $varianten_error .= "Bitte laden sie ein Bild mit korrekter Dateiendung hoch.";
                $fehler = true;
            }
        } elseif ($variante == 3) {
            if (!isset($_POST['bildbreite'])) {
                $varianten_error .= "Bitte geben sie die Breite ihres Bildes an.";
                $fehler = true;
            }elseif (!isset($_POST['bildhoehe'])) {
                $varianten_error .= "Bitte geben sie die Höhe ihres Bildes an.";
                $fehler = true;
            }
        } elseif (isset($_POST['your_email'])) { // robot field
                $fehler = true;
        }else {
            $fehler = false;
        }
        $first_time = false;
    }
    else
    {
        // Ausgabe der Fehlermeldungen und -styles
        $fehler = true;
        $error_style = $pruefung->outStyles;
        echo $error_style;
        $first_time = false;
    }
}

if ( $fehler == true ) {
    $firma = htmlspecialchars($_POST["firma"]);
    $name = htmlspecialchars($_POST["name"]);
    $email = htmlspecialchars($_POST["email"]);
    $tel = htmlspecialchars($_POST["tel"]);
    $plz = htmlspecialchars($_POST["plz"]);
    $ort = htmlspecialchars($_POST["ort"]);
    $strasse = htmlspecialchars($_POST["strasse"]);
    $hausnr = htmlspecialchars($_POST["hausnr"]);
    $hoehe = htmlspecialchars($_POST["hoehe"]);
    $breite = htmlspecialchars($_POST["breite"]);
    $bildhoehe = htmlspecialchars($_POST["bildbreite"]);
    $bildbreite = htmlspecialchars($_POST["bildhoehe"]);
    $upload = $_FILES["upload"];
    echo 
        "<script type='text/javascript'>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $('#errorModal').reveal();
            $('#step0').show();
            $('#step1').hide();
            $('#step2').hide();
            $('#senden').hide();
            selectStep(0);
        });
        </script>";

} elseif ($first_time == false and $fehler == false) {

    SESSION_START();

    $_SESSION["firma"] = htmlspecialchars($_POST["firma"]);
    $_SESSION["name"] = htmlspecialchars($_POST["name"]);
    $_SESSION["email"] = htmlspecialchars($_POST["email"]);
    $_SESSION["tel"] = htmlspecialchars($_POST["tel"]);
    $_SESSION["plz"] = htmlspecialchars($_POST["plz"]);
    $_SESSION["ort"] = htmlspecialchars($_POST["ort"]);
    $_SESSION["strasse"] = htmlspecialchars($_POST["strasse"]);
    $_SESSION["hausnr"] = htmlspecialchars($_POST["hausnr"]);
    $_SESSION["hoehe"] = htmlspecialchars($_POST["hoehe"]);
    $_SESSION["breite"] = htmlspecialchars($_POST["breite"]);
    $_SESSION["bildbreite"] = htmlspecialchars($_POST["bildbreite"]);
    $_SESSION["bildhoehe"] = htmlspecialchars($_POST["bildhoehe"]);
    $_SESSION["upload"] = $_FILES["upload"];
    $_SESSION["src"] = $_FILES["upload"]["tmp_name"];
    $_SESSION["variante"] = $variante;
    $_SESSION["vorlage"] = htmlspecialchars($_POST["vorlagen"]);

    header('Location: ../../assets/scripts/php/auftragform.php');
}else {

    $firma = "";
    $name = "";
    $email = "";
    $tel = "";
    $plz = "";
    $ort = "";
    $strasse = "";
    $hausnr = "";
    $hoehe = "";
    $breite = "";
    $bildhoehe = "";
    $bildbreite = "";
    $upload = "";
}

?>
```

and here is the code of the file handling the data. I´m sure all access rights are given because creating the folder and the .txt file works perfectly fine.

```
<?php 

    include("minimail.php");
    SESSION_START();

    $firma = $_SESSION["firma"];
    $name = $_SESSION["name"];
    $email = $_SESSION["email"];
    $tel = $_SESSION["tel"];
    $plz = $_SESSION["plz"];
    $ort = $_SESSION["ort"];
    $strasse = $_SESSION["strasse"];
    $hausnr = $_SESSION["hausnr"];
    $hoehe = $_SESSION["hoehe"];
    $breite = $_SESSION["breite"];
    $bildhoehe = $_SESSION["bildhoehe"];
    $bildbreite = $_SESSION["bildbreite"];
    $variante = $_SESSION["variante"];
    $vorlage = $_SESSION["vorlage"];

    foreach ($_SESSION as $item => $value) {
        echo "$item: $value <br>";
    }

    foreach ($_SESSION["upload"] as $item => $value) {
        echo "$item: $value <br>";
    }

    function deleteFolder($albumPath){
        $items = scandir($albumPath);

        foreach($items as $item){
            if ($item != "." && $item != "..") {
                $itemPath = $albumPath.'/'.$item;
                if(is_dir($itemPath)){
                    // Unterordner löschen
                    deleteFolder($itemPath);
                }else{
                    // Datei löschen
                    unlink($itemPath);
                }
            }
        }
        rmdir($albumPath);    
    }  

    function create_auftrag ($src = ""){
        echo "funktion aufgerufen";
        $name = $GLOBALS['name'];
        $timestamp = time();
        $datum = date("d.m.Y",$timestamp);
        $oldpath = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/Auftraege/";
        deleteFolder($oldpath);
        mkdir($oldpath);
        chmod($oldpath, 0777);
        $path = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/Auftraege/".$datum.$name."/";
        echo($path);
        $filename = $datum.$name.".txt";
        if(!dirname($path)!= $path) {
            if (mkdir ($path)) 
                { echo "Der Pfad wurde angelegt<br>"; }
            else
                { die("Der Ordner für den Auftrag konnte nicht angelegt werden."); }
        }
        if(file_exists($path.$filename)) 
        { $filename = $datum.$name."_kopie.txt"; }
        $file = fopen($path.$filename, "w");
        // in die Datei schreiben
        $geschrieben = fwrite($file, 
    "
    Name: $name
    Datum: $datum
    Uhrzeit: $uhrzeit
    Firma: ".$GLOBALS['firma']."
    Email: ".$GLOBALS['email']."
    Tel. : ".$GLOBALS['tel']."
    PLZ  : ".$GLOBALS['plz']."
    Ort  : ".$GLOBALS['ort']."
    Strasse : ".$GLOBALS['strasse']."
    Hausnr : ".$GLOBALS['hausnr']."
    Höhe des Sicherungskastens : ".$GLOBALS['hoehe']."
    Breite des Sicherungskastens : ".$GLOBALS['breite']."
    Variante : ".$GLOBALS['variante']."
    Vorlage : ".$GLOBALS['vorlage']."
    Upload : ".$img['name']."
    Bildhoehe : ".$GLOBALS['bildhoehe']."
    Bildbreite : ".$GLOBALS['bildbreite']."
    "
        );
        // Datei schliessen
        fclose($file);
        if(isset($img)){
            move_image($src, $path);
        }
    }

    function move_image($src, $destination) {
        $ziel = $destination.$_SESSION["upload"]["name"];
        echo "$src";
        echo "$ziel";
        while (file_exists($ziel)) {
            $ziel = $destination."kopie_".$img["name"];
        }
        if (rename($src, $ziel)) {
            echo "Bildpuload hat geklappt";
        } else {
            echo "Bildupload hat nicht geklappt";
        }
    }

    function handle_form(){
        $error = false;
        $variante = $GLOBALS['variante'];
        $upload = $GLOBALS['upload'];
        if ($variante == 1) {
            create_auftrag();
        } elseif ($variante == 2) {
            $ziel = $_SESSION["upload"]["tmp_name"]."/".$_SESSION["upload"]["name"];
            echo "$ziel";
            create_auftrag($ziel);
        } elseif ($variante == 3) {
            create_auftrag();
        }
    }

    handle_form();

?>
```

If you want to see it live just head over to http://sicherung.wiv-dev.de/auftrag, but don't wonder about the language, I'm German.
I know the code is huge and the problem quite fuzzy, but I haven't seen any other way than asking you for help.